# dataframeの各列を1列目の値で引きたい

Tags: python, pandas

dataframeの各列を1列目の値で引こうとし、以下のコードで試みたのですが、計算結果のdf2を見ると、1列目は自身の値で引いているので当然0になりますが、他の列は1列目で引かれていなものが返されてしまいます
こちらどのように書き直せばよいか、ご教示いただけると幸いです

```
df2=df

for i in df.columns.values :
    df2[i]=df[i]-df.iloc[:,0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問のコードでは`df2`が`df`の参照となっていますので`df2`を`df`のコピーにすると質問者さんの意図する結果になるかと思います。

```
df2=df.copy()

for i in df.columns.values :
    df2[i]=df[i]-df.iloc[:,0]
```

Answer (score 3):

[pandas.DataFrame.subtract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html) を使う方法もあります。

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
  [
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [3, 6, 9]
  ]
)

df2 = df.sub(df.iloc[:,0], axis=0)
print(df2)
=>
   0  1  2
0  0  3  6
1  0  3  6
2  0  3  6
```

Answer (score 1):

(書き直す感じではないが) この様にも記述可能です

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,11,12,13],[2,21,22,23]], columns=list('ABCD'))

df2 = df.apply(lambda v: v - df['A'])

display(df)
display(df2)
```